# Reduction of 0,1 knapsack to subset sum

Tags: knapsack-problem, reduction, np-complete, subset-sum

I know how to reduce subset sum to 0,1 knapsack. But is it possible to reduce knapsack to subset sum? How?

Answer (score 0):

A reduction from 0,1 knapsack to subset-sum is described in Theorem 2 of the paper ["Reducing a Target Interval to a Few Exact Queries"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4225).  It proceeds in three steps.  First, reduce knapsack to a decision problem that tests whether there is a subset with weight at most b and value at least t.  This can be done by binary search over thresholds.  Second, reduce this decision problem to a small set of exact queries of the form "is there a subset with weight exactly b and value exactly t?"  This is a clever reduction that does not require enumerating all possible b's and t's.  Third, reduce this exact query to subset-sum by mapping each (weight,value) pair into the integer (weight*C + value) for sufficiently large C.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a reduction that, I believe, is fairly simple to understand. Since apparently StackOverflow does not support LaTeX, you can find it as PDF [**here**](https://cloud.uni-konstanz.de/index.php/s/XWKW2CJcRBktnpF). It is based on ideas you also find in modelling Linear Programs, namely slack variables and scaling.